# How do I refresh in PHP

Tags: php, refresh

Hey guys, how do I refresh a PHP page without the header refresh?

Comment: You have said a nonsense.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the header refresh ?

Answer (score 9):

PHP is executed on server. Refresh is a browser funtionnality.

So you have to use javascript or something else executed on browser.

Comment: You just have to send the correct header in PHP in order to refresh. `header("refresh: 5");` would refresh the page every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Vincent: that _is_ executed by the browser - You're just setting the header from php, but it's the same like setting the header in another way or using a Meta-tag.

Comment: Well, yes, but what does this have to do with anything? Luc M told him he had to use javascript or something else, you can do it in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript:

```
window.location.href = refreshedUrl;
```

Answer (score 2):

header-refresh is the way to go. another solution would be to use javascript, but thats even more ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Java script.

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

You can use Java script timer to refresh your page every x minutes.

Comment: Why alter the `href`?  Why not just `window.location.reload(false)` or `history.go(0)`?

Comment: Obviously, because I don't like history.go(0) and this is how I did it in my project I guess there might be another way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular HTML meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple ^^ Just Use This And It works For PHP :)

```html
echo "<script>window.location = window.location.href;</script>";
```